# Why does pointer value is being used as . instead of -> in this

Tags: c

```
    struct AdjListNode
    {
        int dest;
        struct AdjListNode* next;
    };

    // A structure to represent an adjacency list
    struct AdjList
    {
        struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
    };

    // A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
    // Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
    struct Graph
    {
        int V;
        struct AdjList* array;
    };


    struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
    {
        struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
        graph->V = V;

        // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
        graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

         // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
            graph->array[i].head = NULL;

        return graph;
    }

    // Adds an edge to an undirected graph
    void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest)
    {
        // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is added to the adjacency
        // list of src.  The node is added at the begining
        struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest);
        newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
        graph->array[src].head = newNode;

        // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from dest to src also
        newNode = newAdjListNode(src);
        newNode->next = grap`enter code here`h->array[dest].head;
        graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
    }
```

Specifically

```
graph->array[i].head = NULL;
```

- Ok so the graph is a pointer of type Graph
- hence uses -> to access array which is an object of graph of type AdjList
  which has  a
  pointer of type AdjListNode which is also a pointer.

Since *array member in Graph is a pointer to AdjList then why is

```
graph->array[i]->head =  NULL;
```

not used ?

I know that `.` operator is used when we access a member of struct which is not a pointer.

```
somestructpointer -> itsmember
```

is basically sugar coating

```
(*somestructpointer).itsmember
```

I don't understand what's happening. HELP.

Comment: Is `graph->array[i]` a pointer? Why or why not?

Comment: Translating the sugar of `graph->array[i]`, this is equivalent to `graph->(*(array+i))`: as you see, the array is dereferenced, so `graph->array[i].head` is accessing non pointer resources, thus the `.`

Comment: @wasthishelpful `graph->(*(array+i))` is wrong, `*(graph->array+i)` is equivalent to `graph->array[i]`.

Comment: @mch looks like I wasn't thinking when writing. Thx for pointing the mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graph` is a pointer.
`graph->array`dereferences the above pointer to to get to the array variable.
`graph->array[i]` uses array notation to reach a member at position `i`.

The member we reach is of type `struct AdjList`, which is not a pointer. It's a `struct`. So a dot(`.`) is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

`AdjList* array` is a pointer to an array of data. Basically, writing `array[i]` is equivalent to writing `*(array + i)`.

So we have:

```
graph->array[i].head
```

becomes

```
(*(graph->array + i)).head
```

As a funny Bonus and to confuse you further, you can also write `i[array]`, as that too is basically `*(i + array)`.

Comment: `i` is not an array and doesn't have `operator[]`. No need to make things more confuse :)

Comment: @wasthishelpful, arrays don't have `operator[]` either (this isn't C++ after all). `a[b]` is just a binary operator between `a` and `b`.

Comment: Sorry for the malapropism, that was obviously the idea. I will use a proper formulation next time ;)